# Create different stroke styles on same Path - SwiftUI (Based on value between 0-1 like gradient)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, shapes, swiftui-environment

In SwiftUI Shapes we can make different color strokes by using gradients.

Eg -

```
@ViewBuilder
func lineWithSecondColorStyleFromPositionN() -> some View {
    let n = 0.5
    GeometryReader { gr in
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: gr.size.width, y: gr.size.height))
        }
        .stroke(
            LinearGradient(stops: [
                Gradient.Stop(color: .red, location: 0),
                Gradient.Stop(color: .red, location: n),
                Gradient.Stop(color: .blue, location: n),
                Gradient.Stop(color: .blue, location: 1)
            ], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
            style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .butt)
        )
    }
    .frame(height: 200)
}
```

[image]

Is it possible by any means to do the same for stroke styles?

To create something like this -

[image]

Stroke Style 1(Full Line) from 0 to `n`,

Stroke Style 2(Dashed) from `n` to 1.

Where `n` can be any floating number `0<=n<=1`

Comment: You are not showing minimal, reproducible lines of code.

Comment: What about drawing twice, one with dash$, one with full lines, and use a mask to hide the parts you want?

Comment: Tried that.. became too cumbersome.. But will look into it with some other angle..

Comment: Was looking to see if there's some way to avoid drawing twice.
But don't think soo..

Comment: Thanks for the followup - I'm in the same situation, trying to avoid double-draw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only Gradient to achieve this I think